# Is it possible to preload a JavaScript file one page earlier than it will be used?

Tags: javascript, caching, dojo

Because of a system of dependencies that are less formalized than I'd like, I now have a very, very large "master" JS file that contains a pretty large kitchen sink for use in every page in my app; that is, once you've logged in.

It only takes a few seconds to load, but those few seconds aren't great for a first-time experience at the logged-in homepage. So, I'd like to find a way of loading my script on my login page, so that when the browser requests it on the homepage, it either gets a 304 Not Modified response, or simply knows not to re-request it. Here's what I've tried.

### Just including the `<script>`

This unfortunately doesn't work because the script in question doesn't have "definition guards" in place. Including it on the page messes up the login page because of certain `<div>`s it expects to have present. It's built through dojo, and I don't want to hack the built file, so I don't want to surround its code in such a check.

### Grab it with XHR

I actually had this fix in place for a while, and it appears to work okay in Chrome; once the login page is completely loaded, my script then sends out an XHR to "js/masterFile.js" and does nothing with it. The assumption is that as long as the cache headers are okay, the browser will hold onto it when it later needs that file as a script. As I said, it turns out most browsers don't seem to work this way. Some reuse the "text" they got from the XHR, others seem to cache scripts differently from other content; it's possible that's a security-related issue to them.

### Load it in an iframe

This is kind of entering rocky territory, as I don't like iframes, and it's an extra request. But, doing this would at least let the browser cache the script in the right way. It introduces a lot of code complication though, and I'm hesitant to settle on this.

If it helps at all, the scripts are AMD-compatible; but, the master script in question is a "boot layer" that contains the basic definitions of require/define.

Comment: You could always extend your _XHR_ fix to stuff the code into _sessionStorage_

Comment: @PaulS. Hm...And then run eval() on the next page? That's...an interesting way of fixing it. I'd need to think over whether it has security implications. Also, I'd want to be certain that this wouldn't mess up anything trying to retrieve it via AMD (which, of course, would first look for an actual script file if it's not in its cache store)

Comment: why do you overcomplicate things? If iframe works why not use it? For me it sounds even better workaround than doing some ajax call (even if it would work across all browsers)

Comment: I was thinking in part that it would need me to code an iframe anytime I want to preload a script, but I hadn't really thought about whether manually accessing a self-made iframe through JS might work. I might revisit it later.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I just found a possible way of doing this; I don't currently have time to thoroughly test it, but it appears to work on a basic level.

```
<script src="myMasterScript.js" type="text/definitelynotjavascriptnopenosir"></script>
```

*This* works in an interesting way. I can see that the request is made for the script source, AND if it's valid JavaScript, it will execute. (As found from just referring to the JQuery CDN) However, the browser's console will essentially squelch any kind of errors that occur from running it; ie, "Oh. Maybe I wasn't supposed to run that".

For my own purposes, I still need to figure out, based on the JQuery scenario, whether this might still mess up the page to some degree.